# Trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to get the roots for a complex number $x^2+1$

$x^2+1=0\rightarrow x^2=-1 \rightarrow x = \sqrt{-1} \rightarrow i$

So, $w^2 = 0 + 1i$

$p = \sqrt{0^2+1^2} = 1$

$\theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{0} \right )$

But I don't know what I can do to get the $\tan^{-1}(\frac10)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\infty) =\dfrac{\pi}2$ because the real part and the imajinary part are positive and if the real part and the imajinary part are negative also we have $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, if one of this side is negative and the other is positive then $\theta=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve $x^2 = -1$,
note that both
$x = i$ and $x = -i$
satisfies this equation.

Remember that, aside from $0$,
all complex numbers have
2 square roots, 3 cube roots,
and $n$ $n$-th roots for any positive integer $n$.